# "too much data for sort()" error in meteor sitemap generator method

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor, sitemap

I used meteor [sitemaps](https://atmospherejs.com/gadicohen/sitemaps) package to generate sitemap using below code:

```
Meteor.methods({
    sitemapsGenerator: function (generateAnyway) {
        var setting = Settings.findOne({ title: 'sitemapsLastGenerateDate'});

        if (generateAnyway || (new Date(setting.lastModified.getTime()+(24*60*60*1000)) < new Date)) {
            console.log("sitemap generator called");
            var generalSitemapUrls = [];
            for (var i = 0; i <= Math.round(MyPosts.find().count() / 10000); i++) {
                sitemaps.add('/sitemap' + i + '.xml', (function (i) {
                    var out = [];
                    MyPosts.find({}, {
                        fields: {title: 1, postDate: 1},
                        sort: {postDate: 1}, limit: 10000, skip: i * 10000
                    }).forEach(function (post) {
                        console.log("sitemap called" + i);
                        out.push({
                            page: "/posts/" + post.title + "/" + post._id,
                            lastmod: post.postDate,
                            changefreq: 'weekly'
                        });
                    });
                    return out;
                })(i));
            }

            Settings.update({title: "sitemapsLastGenerateDate"}, {$set: {lastModified: new Date} });
        }
    }
});
```

Now after 2 month my collection size was growing up and recently I got below error when try to generate sitemap:

```
MongoError: too much data for sort() with no index.  add an index or
specify a smaller limit.
```

What is the solution to fix this error?

If this error fix by adding index to collection field how to do this in meteor?

Answer (score 1):

on your collection object you use ensureIndex.  Typically you do this on your server side, on startup.

Comment: Can you explain more about it? What about existing data. Is this risky?

Comment: no risk adding an index.  It's more to do with mongo than Meteor, and you can read a lot about it on the Mongo site, or any mongo resources discussing indexes ... just for future reference, if you want full text search, then you also do that with a mongo index as well, so good to read up on it all